# RabbitMQ Upgrade from 3.8.2 to 3.8.6 on Debian -- How to Install Latest Version?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to upgrade RabbitMQ on a cluster of two Linux VMs created via Bitnami in Azure (running Debian 9 Stretch) from version 3.8.2 to the newest version, 3.8.6. According to [RabbitMQ's documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/upgrade.html#rolling-upgrades), I can do a rolling upgrade by stopping one of the nodes, installing the newest version on it, restarting that node, and then doing the same on the other node. The machines are running with Erlang 22, which RabbitMQ states is compatible with the 3.8.6 release:

```
bitnami@AI-RabbitMQ-02:~$  erl -eval 'erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt().'  -noshell
"22"
```

Following the [documentation steps for installation using PackageCloud](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-packagecloud), I've installed the repository successfully, with this output:

```
bitnami@AI-RabbitMQ-02:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app

bitnami@AI-RabbitMQ-02:~$ curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.deb.sh | sudo bash                                                                                                          abbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
Detected operating system as debian/9.
Checking for curl...
Detected curl...
Checking for gpg...
Detected gpg...
Running apt-get update... done.
Installing debian-archive-keyring which is needed for installing
apt-transport-https on many Debian systems.
Installing apt-transport-https... done.
Installing /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server.list...done.
Importing packagecloud gpg key... done.
Running apt-get update... done.
The repository is setup! You can now install packages.
```

Then, I try the next step, to install RabbitMQ, being presented with the following errors:

```
bitnami@AI-RabbitMQ-02:~$ sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server=3.8.6-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-base (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3 i                                                                                                             s to be installed or
                            erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:21.3) but it is not going to                                                                                                              be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-crypto (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3                                                                                                              is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-eldap (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3                                                                                                              is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-inets (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3                                                                                                              is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-mnesia (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3                                                                                                              is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-os-mon (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3                                                                                                              is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-parsetools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+de                                                                                                             b9u3 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-public-key (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+de                                                                                                             b9u3 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-runtime-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2                                                                                                             +deb9u3 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-ssl (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3 is                                                                                                              to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-syntax-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+                                                                                                             deb9u3 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3                                                                                                              is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-xmerl (>= 1:21.3) but 1:19.2.1+dfsg-2+deb9u3                                                                                                              is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've attempted to do the install with the Bintray option as well, but to no avail. I've tried installing manually with `dpkg -i` as well, but I'm not sure how to handle the package dependencies, since the link on Rabbit's page for that step [doesn't lead anywhere](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#package-dependencies). Any help with the upgrade would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had Erlang 23 and RabbitMQ Server 3.8.2 (they are not fully compatible so I decided to upgrade RabbitMQ Server to 3.8.9 because I had some problems running my app)

I have a cluster with one node on AWS EC2 instance of Ubuntu 20.04 (unconfigured yet properly as RabbitMQ advises via plugin - I plan to do it later).

What I did and it worked for me (following commands executed under `sudo` or root `sudo su`):

1. It's important to `shutdown` not just `stop_app` as Erlang also needs to be stopped and `stop_app` only stops RabbitMQ Server leaving Erlang on which would later might give you error while starting new version of the RabbitMQ Server - for port 25672 being busy with another app:

   `rabbitmqctl shutdown`
2. Change in rabbitmq file from old version (I had for some strange reason 3.8.8 instead of 3.8.2 which I run) to a new one - in my case 3.8.9:

   `vim /etc/apt/preferences.d/rabbitmq`
3. Recheck if dependencies are installed:

   `apt-get -y install socat logrotate init-system-helpers adduser`
4. Install wget if you don't have it:

   `apt-get -y install wget`
5. Download latest .deb package of server installation file:

   `wget https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/download/v3.8.9/rabbitmq-server_3.8.9-1_all.deb`
6. Install it:

   `dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.8.9-1_all.deb`
7. Remove distro:

   `rm rabbitmq-server_3.8.9-1_all.deb`
8. Check if server stopped (may be redundant command):

   `service rabbitmq-server stop`
9. Restart server:

   `service rabbitmq-server restart`
10. Check server status:

    `rabbitmq-server status`
11. If it gives you an error BOOT FAILED. Distribution port 25672 is in use by another node, check who uses that port it may be that Erlang uses that port:

    `lsof -i :25672`
12. Start RabbitMQ app:

    `rabbitmqctl start_app`
13. Check status of node:

    `rabbitmqctl status`

You should see upgraded RabbitMQ Server version (in my case 3.8.9) along with you recent Erlang version (in my case 23)

Comment: Thank you! I ended up changing endpoints to a newly-created set of VMs created via Bitnami, then deleting the VM with the older 3.8.2 once the switchover was complete. Since the newly-created machines through Bitnami had version 3.8.9, the setup was "updated." However, that means the machines will need to be deleted again to update in the future, so I will definitely be trying the steps you've detailed here down the line for updating. I greatly appreciate your help!